# How to Use Rails Code for A Mailing List Signup Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Looking for a "railsy" way to code a simple email signup form that include a name, email address, and twitter handle that will store the info in a database. I am using Rails 4.0.0 with ruby ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386)

I am familiar with HTML forms, but still learning rails.

Comment: Go through the Rails Guide and once you're done, you should have a feeling on how to create forms and persist data using ActiveRecord.

Comment: are you referring to the official for guide by hart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick tutorial I conjured up:

**The rails equivalent of `<form>`**

Use the `form-for` to create an equivalent to an HTML form. Use this code to create a form:

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Replace `@user` with the variable in your controller. For example, if you had `@email = Email.new` in the create action of your controller, you would use `@email'. This is what you store your data in. The`|f|`basically helps you by returning code with the specified input type, and assigns it to your`@user` object you just defined.

**Checking for errors**

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<h2>You have <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> in this form:</h2>
     <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
```

This basically checks the input given by the user comparing it to the validations you made in your model, and loops through all the errors and prints them out. The pluralize method is quite interesting, it takes two params, a number and a word to pluralize. If the number is more than one , it pluralizes the given word. If not, it keeps it's form. It doesn't just add an `s` to the end but it goes into a database and searches for a word `error`. This means that it can handle words like `woman`.

**Adding a text field**

Using the `f` we passed into the `form_for` block eariler, we can create text-boxes. This can be done by the following code:

```
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
```

The first line, creates a label. The second is the line where we define a new text field and tell rails we want to assign it's value to the `:email` column in your database. There are many more things like f.text_field, all which can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html). To add classes, type `f.text_field :email, class: "class-name"` and for placeholders, `f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email"`.

**Submit button**

Now for the last bit, the submit button.

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

And you are done! Bare in mind that there is *quite a lot* of backend stuff you need to do which I have not mentioned. For a full tutorial on making a user system see [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up).